# Is there in typescript a common super class for all object like in Java?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method which can return any type of object in my typescript project.
In java you would just return Object and then the caller has to cast.
How would you do that in Typescript ?
Do all classes inherit from a common super class like the Java Object type ??

Comment: You can use `any` (also take a look at `unknown`), but the comparison to Java's `Object` type doesn't really hold. And just like when using `Object` in Java, having to use `any` in TypeScript is often a symptom of underlying problems with your type system (barring some exceptional cases).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I think it's worth to mention `object` type (lowercased).

Comment: @RoboRobok I mentioned `object` in a comment on one of the answers below. That answer was updated and i removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you need anything and you will know later what it is, use `unknown` (you will need to use `as type` later):

```js
function test(): unknown {
  return { a: 0, b: 1 };
}

test().a // Error
(test() as {a:number,b:number}).a // Ok
```

If you won't know and care what it is, use `any` (but this case typesafety goes out of the window):

```js
function test(): any {
  return { a: 0, b: 1 };
}

test().a // Ok
```

If you know at least it's object, you can type it as `object` and use Object functions or access it through type guards:

```js
function test(): object {
  return { a: 0, b: 1 };
}

Object.keys(test()) // Ok

// Or use with type guard:

const tst = test()
if ("a" in tst) {
    tst.a // Ok
}
```

Also see [Assignability documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#any-unknown-object-void-undefined-null-and-never-assignability).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen True, I corrected answer.

Answer (score -2):

Most of the time the caller will know what to expect. What you can do is to infer the type when calling the function like so:

```typescript
class A {
  public returnAnyThing<T>(): T {
    return {} as T;
  }
}

interface ReturnValue {
    val: number;
}

class Caller {
    public call(){
        const returnValue = new A().returnAnyThing<ReturnValue>();
        console.log(returnValue.val);
    }
}
```